# Why Glightbox is not showing in index?

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to open my index file, the video I've put there is not opening. When I open the site with liver server though it works and the video is showing just fine.

I can't figure out, why in index only it doesn't show, but in live server it works?

```html
<a href="#" class="glightbox position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">
  <span>
    <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
  </span>
  <span class="border-animation border-animation--border-1"></span>
  <span class="border-animation border-animation--border-2"></span>
</a>
```

```js
const lightbox = GLightbox({
  href: "https://youtu.be/7lJPlgkduw4",
  type: "video",
  source: "youtube", //vimeo, youtube or local
  width: 900,
  autoPlayVideos: "true",
});
```

Comment: I think that if you open your Developer Tools you might read out loud some errors. If there's any - what was your research to address them?

Comment: `<script src="/assets/vendors/js/glightbox.min.js"></script>` problem is there I think. Should've started with `./` ? I've seen it before edit question has done.

Comment: Well guys i fixed it. The problem was the path to my index.html folder. Big tnx to @RokoC.Buljan for telling me to look into the developer tools --Yea tnx man there was said about the path 
Thank you guys :)